# Car stalls after running

Tags: chrysler, stall, concorde

My 94 Chrysler Concorde stalls after it runs a few miles. It will start up again after I wait a few minutes or stalls but to eventually kick over just to do the same thing again. I had the carburetor cleaned and thermostat changed. It ran a little better afterwards, but the next day started back to original stall and run again.

Comment: Welcome to mechanics.se. You used the tag power-windows but didn't mention anything about windows in the question - are they related somehow, or was the tag a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get your vehicle serviced?

I am pretty sure that '94 Concordes don't have carburetors; so I am curious who charged you for this service and if it is a wise idea to go back to them. That year/model is fuel injected and they *could* have serviced your fuel injection system, but that is different than a carb cleaning; you should verify with your mechanic what exactly was done and make sure they are not charging you for something that is simply not possibly on that vehicle.

Further, and more to your question, are there any other indications of an issue? The biggest indication that one would look for are **service lights** being **on**. For example, is your check engine light on? I reckon it might be and the best course of action is to take it to a mechanic and have him see what is causing the light to be on (error code); just be sure to take it to someone who hasn't charged you for a carb cleaning on a fuel injected car.

There are numerous reasons why this might happen, but we need more details to help you. Does it stall at a certain time consistently (like idling)? The more details you can provide the better we can help you.